# Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Async operation timed out

Tags: websphere

I am facing issue while deploying applications through Websphere Admin Console. I have read lot of posts regarding this but none of them seemed to work. Below are the tunings I have done in admin console level but ended with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated , Thanks!

1. Application servers > server1 > Web container > Asynchronous Servlet Properties - Increased to 120000 ms
2. Application servers > server1 > Web container transport chains > WCInboundAdmin > HTTP inbound channel (HTTP_1) > Custom properties > ConnectionIOTimeOut set to 30
3. Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom properties [ com.ibm.ws.webservices.readTimeout - 90000
   com.ibm.ws.webservices.writeTimeout - 90000
   ]

Error : FFDC logs

```
10/3/17 9:49:52:174 EDT]     FFDC Exception:java.net.SocketTimeoutException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferInputStream ProbeId:102 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferInputStream@cd1d12ca
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Async operation timed out
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.processSyncReadRequest(AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPReadRequestContextImpl.read(TCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:111)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.fillABuffer(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:4327)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.readSingleBlock(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:3508)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.readBodyBuffer(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:3614)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.getRequestBodyBuffer(HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.java:1838)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferInputStream.bufferIsGood(WCCByteBufferInputStream.java:397)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferInputStream.read(WCCByteBufferInputStream.java:291)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.http.HttpInputStream.read(HttpInputStream.java:322)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.skipPreamble(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.upload.CommonsMultipartRequestHandler.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.controller.NLSDiskMultipartRequestHandler.handleRequest(NLSDiskMultipartRequestHandler.java:42)
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:514)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:335)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3980)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.ibm.io.async.AsyncTimeoutException(Async operation timed out, [Timeout, rc=0])
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.waitForCompletion(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:359)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.getByteCount(AsyncFuture.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioSocketIOChannel.readAIOSync(AioSocketIOChannel.java:215)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.processSyncReadRequest(AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:184)
    ... 50 more
```

Websphere console logs  :-

```
[10/3/17 9:49:52:256 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Async operation timed out
[10/3/17 9:49:52:257 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.upload.CommonsMultipartRequestHandler.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:257 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.isclite.container.controller.NLSDiskMultipartRequestHandler.handleRequest(NLSDiskMultipartRequestHandler.java:42)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:257 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(Unknown Source)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:257 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(Unknown Source)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:257 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:257 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:258 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:258 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:258 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:258 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:258 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:258 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:259 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:259 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:259 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:259 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:967)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:259 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:514)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:259 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:335)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:260 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:260 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:260 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:260 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:260 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3980)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:260 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:261 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:261 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:261 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:261 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:261 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:262 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:262 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:262 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:262 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:262 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:262 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:263 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:263 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:263 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:263 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:263 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Async operation timed out
[10/3/17 9:49:52:264 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(Unknown Source)
[10/3/17 9:49:52:264 EDT] 00000074 SystemErr     R  ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been long time since question was asked. But i guess this will help somebody else in future.

This is a workaround, not an answer, really, but I found out that it has something to do with installing from the "Local file system" option. Using the "Remote file system" option, even though the WAR file was on my local drive, works.